# How to remove a stylesheet provided by a contrib module?

Tags: 7, theming

The new version of Field Group has a new stylesheet included by default that makes my theme look hideous.  Deleting the stylesheet from the module's folder fixes the problem but then I will have to delete it again when Field Group is updated again.

What's the right way (= not modifying the module's code directly) to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think using [`hook_css_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7) in a custom module/theme would be the easiest solution:

```
function MYMODULE_css_alter(&$css) {
  // Get the path to the module
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'field_group');

  // Remove the unneeded files from the css array
  unset($css[$path . '/field_group.css']);
  unset($css[$path . '/field_group.field_ui.css']);
}
```

There are also other CSS files in the Field Group module:

- horizontal-tabs/horizontal-tabs.css
- multipage/multipage.css

In case you're look to remove absolutely all the CSS that Field Group introduces.

Comment: Thank you! In this case I only needed to remove `multipage/multipage.css`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this in your theme's `.info` file.  Check out [the documentation from drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/263967).

If you want to remove css, just add a line like this in your .info file:

`stylesheets[all][] = system-menus.css`

If you have a stylesheet by that name in your theme, then that will replace the one provided by the module.  If you don't have that stylesheet in your theme, then Drupal will just omit that stylesheet altogether.

Looks like there was [a bug](https://drupal.org/node/967166) with this method for a while, but it has seemingly been fixed.